# Firebase Auth Register without login

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I just wanted to ask how I can register a user to Firebase Auth but I don't want him to log in right then. When a user registers, they currently login directly but I don't want this. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: "When a user registers, they currently login directly" Please show the minimal code that reproduces the problem you have here. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [firebase anonymous login](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth), to register user on firebaes authentication and then later when user can login with various authenticatino method like google, mobile, facebook, etc and you can link these [multiple auth provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking) to the above user